# How do I test Google Analytics? AnalyticsForWindowsPhone isn't working

Tags: google-analytics, windows-phone-8

Has anyone gotten this library to work with Windows Phone 8?  I have followed all of the steps in [this page](http://devatheart.azurewebsites.net/2012/09/02/analytics-for-windows-phone-nuget-to-rule-them-all/), and nothing is showing up on Google.  Nothing live, no events...  Nothing.  I set up the Google Analytics site last week.  I also tried [this analytics package](http://mark.mymonster.nl/2013/01/18/google-analytics-now-also-on-your-windows-phone-8-app-in-1-minute), and get nothing from it, as well.  If anyone has gotten it to work, are there tricks to it that aren't obvious on these pages?  I'm curious if there is a way to test my PropertyID from Google, to see if it works - like a URL I can type in with parameters, for instance, just to see if it works.

Thanks.

Comment: Same here.  I tried the steps on the "1-minute" article.  Doesn't work for my WP8 app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did get Google Analytics to work.  I ended up going with Flurry, which is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Raman,

I'm the creator of the MSAF.GoogleAnalytics nuget package. Did you try with fiddler to see if the actual HTTP requests come through?

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, but I am now using GoogleAnalyticsTracker and it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

To see the Real-Time data, you need to track it via Page Tracking, but not not Custom Category, Action or Label.